# Image not displaying in flutter from assets

Tags: flutter

Hi in the below code Image is not displaying from assets folder. I added pubspec also still image is not displaying .

Can any one help me I am new to flutter

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login_screen.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                    name: "Sai Gopi",
                  )),
          (route) => false);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0769AA),
      body: Center(
          child: Image.asset('assets/images/genvcarelogo.png'),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubspec.yml:

```
assets:
    - images/genvcarelogo.png
```

Comment: Make sure your indentation in pubspec.yaml is proper otherwise image will not be displayed.
Also make sure you have add the image in assets/images folders too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify all the images in pubspec.yaml, just add the root folder containing your all the images like this:

```
assets:
- assets/images/
```

And use like you already using it:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/genvcarelogo.png')
```

Comment: not working.......

Comment: Why accept an answer that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the image in `pubspec.yaml` and in code is differing and the indentation in your pubspec is wrong. If the path in the code is right then update your pubspec to this,

```
assets:
  - assets/images/genvcarelogo.png
```

(Make sure there are only two spaces in the second line.)

Comment: not working stil I am getting unable to load the genvcarelogo.png

Comment: Did you detach the app and run again after editing the pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

if you've made sure everything is correct in your `pubspec.yaml` (i.e image location is correct and indentations are right) then all you need to do is stop the application completely and rerun it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).